# JSON data not working

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to figure out why the code below is not working. It works fine when the numbers are directly inserted into the variable (in the code below it's commented out). The alert from the variable extracted from JSON is also showing up fine, but when the variable extracted from JSON is inserted into  map.setCenter or google.maps.Marker it does not work.

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_button', function(){
  var property_id = $('#property_id').val();
  $.post('sql_search_by_id.php', {id : property_id}, function(data){
     var json = $.parseJSON(data);
     var lt = json.results[0].latitude;
     var lg = json.results[0].longitude;
     alert(lt + " - " + lg);
    //var lt = 49; var lg = 15;
   map.setCenter({lat: lt, lng: lg});
   new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: lt, lng: lg}, map: map});
  });
});
```

Comment: What the `json` variable contains after the `var json = $.parseJSON(data);` ? Did you check ?

Comment: which return type do you get running parseJSON function, do you get null from $.parseJSON(data), or any other data?

Comment: If I insert "alert(json);" after "var json = $.parseJSON(data);" I get "[object Object]".

Comment: If I use alert to show whats in "var lt = json.results[0].latitude;" it gives me the exact number I need.

Comment: Try using parseInt or parseFloat whichever you require.
like `var lt = parseInt( json.results[0].latitude);`

Comment: @WisdmLabs This worked. Put it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using parseInt or parseFloat whichever you require.

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_button', function(){
      var property_id = $('#property_id').val();
      $.post('sql_search_by_id.php', {id : property_id}, function(data){
         var json = $.parseJSON(data);
         var lt = parseInt(json.results[0].latitude);
         var lg = parseInt(json.results[0].longitude);
         alert(lt + " - " + lg);
        //var lt = 49; var lg = 15;
       map.setCenter({lat: lt, lng: lg});
       new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: lt, lng: lg}, map: map});
      });
    });
```